# LOS Recorder without unlocking

Tags: lock-screens, lineageos, audio-recording

It is possible to use the camera without unlocking the Phone (I am using Lineage OS 14.1 on Samsung S4)

But now I would also like to use the Lineage OS Recorder App without unlocking. I often use it for short notices to myself and its really a pain to always type my unlock code for 5 seconds of recording...

Is there a way to use the Recorder App that way? Or is there any other app on fdroid to do so?

Comment: Yes. You can start recording and lock the phone. Recording be continued without pause/stop

Comment: thats not what I want, I want to START recording without unlocking the phone, just like taking a photo without unlocking

Comment: Hmmm. Okay. Try use Termux application. Install it + termux api. Then you can take a photo from.script `termux-camera-photo`. Not requires root access.

Comment: mh, sorry can you say that again? :) so termux is a terminal for android, thats nice, but how should I use that on my problem? Your last sentence is confusing me

Comment: Ohh, sorry for my little english. I not understand what you want. Camera photo or video?

Comment: Considering there's no customization for LOS' lock screen, I think the only way is to use 3rd-party lock screen that allows shortcut customization